# Get a single string out of a ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, substring

I have a ListBox with X Items in it. An Item is build up like String, double, double. I want that the item with the smalles value of the second double gets shown together with its string in a Label.

An example Item: Name Value1 Value2
So every part is devided by spaces. The code works only for getting the smallest value of the second double yet, but doesnt take the string of that item.

The function of vName doesn't work.

```
    private void bVergleich_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox.Items.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte erst Einträge hinzufügen.");
        }
        else
        {
            int anzahl = listBox.Items.Count;
            string str = listBox.Items[anzahl].ToString();
            string vName = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

            var numbers = listBox.Items.Cast<string>().Select(obj => decimal.Parse(obj.Split(' ').First(), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

            decimal minValue = listBox.Items.Cast<string>().Select(obj => decimal.Parse(obj.Split(' ').Last(), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).Min();

            lVergleich.Content = vName + " " + minValue + "€";
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how I can get the string too?

Comment: I'd recommend to use a data item class (with appropriate properties) instead of strings for your ListBox items. Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: I expect your values(2nd double) not to be distinct or?=!

Comment: @Clemens do you got any other idea than using a Data Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try using your code example. You could use the old school approach and run with a for-loop through all entries.

```
private void bVergleich_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.Items.Count <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte erst Einträge hinzufügen.");
    }
    else
    {
        List<decimal> tmpListe = new List<decimal>();
        int anzahl = listBox.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
        {
            string str = listBox.Items[i].ToString();
            // collect all the second double values
            tmpListe.Add(decimal.Parse(str.Split(' ').Last(), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        }

        // get the minimal value and its index
        decimal minValue = tmpListe.Min();
        int index = tmpListe.IndexOf(tmpListe.Min());

        // use the index to get the name
        string str2 = listBox.Items[index].ToString();
        string vName = str2.Substring(0, str2.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

        // write down your comparison
        lVergleich.Content = vName + " " + minValue + "€";
    }
}
```

This should display you the **first** lowest value in your List.

personally I would also suggest to use a custom class with 3 properties and an overridden `ToString` method for display. Then collect all the items in a generic `List` and bind this List to the `ListBox`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly :) But you did a little mistake in the line:            string vName = str.Substring(0, str2.IndexOf(" ") + 1); It shows an error this way. It works with:         string vName = str2.Substring(0, str2.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

Comment: thank you for the hint. typical copy paste mistake. I corrected it. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your collection by the desired value and take the first element in sequence

```
List<string> list = listBox.Items.ToList();

list.Sort((x1, x2) => decimal.Compare(decimal.Parse(x1.Split(' ')[1]), decimal.Parse(x2.Split(' ')[1])));

string x = list.First();
```

Or just

```
string result = listBox.Items.OrderBy(y =>  decimal.Parse(y.Split(' ')[1])).First();
```

Comment: No matter which one I try to use it always tells me that "it does not contain a definition for 'ToList'/'OrderBy' and no extension method..."

Tried some different using statements but it does not really help.
What do I have to do?

Comment: What is the type of listBox.Items? And make sure you have reference to Linq library

Comment: One listBox Item is made out of 3 strings

Comment: Is it an Observable Collection of your type? Is it one string with spaces or a different type?

Comment: Between each string is a space. Just to make sure, here is my code:
listBox.Items.Add(sName + " " + "[Annuitätendarlehen]" + " " + Annuitätenrechner.zmErg.ToString("0.00") + "€" + " " + Annuitätenrechner.zgErg.ToString("0.00") + "€");

Comment: Try to use cast to string "listBox.Items.Cast<string>()"